# Getting error when try to add docker swarm manager into multipass VM

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-swarm, multipass

I have tried to launch two multipass VM. After installing docker in the multipass, I am trying to initialize docker swarm in one of the multipass vm. The command is:

```
multipass exec node1 -- /bin/bash -c 'docker swarm init --advertise-addr 10.173.198.201:2377 --listen-addr 10.173.198.201:2377'
```

But then the error comes up. It says:

```
Error response from daemon: advertise address must be a non-zero IP address or network interface (with optional port number)
```

Now how can I solve the issue? Can I launch multipass without 0 in IP?

Comment: Is that IP address assigned to your machine? If not, have you tried to use that? Your machine should be assigned with an IP which looks something like `192.168.xxx.xxx` if you use a home router.

Comment: When I have launched new multipass VM, my machine automatically assigned this IP `10.173.198.201` to the multipass VM.

Comment: What about world-famous `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Finally `127.0.0.1` saves my day. So the command should be: `multipass exec node1 -- /bin/bash -c 'docker swarm init --advertise-addr 127.0.0.1'`

Comment: Will I add it to the answer? So that it may work as a reference for others?

Comment: Sure rumon vai. I will be pleased if you upvote my question ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` would save your day!